# Unable to locate package python-gnomedesktop

Tags: apt

While installing:
`sudo apt-get install python-gnomedesktop python-rsvg ipython`

I receive the error:
`E: Unable to locate package python-gnomedesktop`

Comment: did you follow any link?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: tried everything...downloaded key, added debian port then again do update and tried again....but did not worked

Comment: Could you add more details? Please post the complete output of the command you are trying to run plus the output of `apt-cache policy python-gnomedesktop`

Answer (score 0):

You wrongly written the package name.It's not `python-gnomedesktop` it's `python-gnome2-desktop`.So try the below commands to install that,

```
sudo apt-get install python-gnome2-desktop
sudo apt-get install python-rsvg
sudo apt-get install ipython
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install python-gnome2-desktop python-rsvg ipython
```

Comment: actually i am installing ndnSIM from ndnsim.net/getting-started.html‎  everything I have done according to the instructions given there. Could not able to install. Now I have changed to Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: ndnSIM has been successfully compiled and used under Ubuntu Linux 12.04 (boost libraries 1.48, with default version 1.46 compilation will probably fail), 12.10 (default version of boost 1.49), 13.04 (default version of boost 1.49), Fedora 18, Mac OS 10.7 and 10.8 (gcc-4.2 apple/llvm, macports gcc 4.7, boost 1.49-1.54).

Comment: But your'e running 13.10